# Iterating through my fonts list to display them more efficiently

Tags: java, android, loops

**Answer located here:** [Setting multiple different Typefaces to the TextViews in a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349006/setting-multiple-different-typefaces-to-the-textviews-in-a-listview/34349042#34349042)

I have 20 fonts in a list that changes a TextView based on the user's selection. I want to keep adding more custom fonts, but it's getting very tedious doing this manually for each addition. In the following use case, the user presses a button that opens a menu (not shown). I want to display these buttons in their respective fonts, by setting a typeface to each TextView in the menu:

```
Typeface Aclonica = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Aclonica.ttf");
TextView fontMenuAclonica = (TextView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.fontMenuAclonica);
fontMenuAclonica.setTypeface(Aclonica);

Typeface Arimo = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Arimo-Regular.ttf");
TextView fontMenuArimo = (TextView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.fontMenuArminoRegular);
fontMenuArimo.setTypeface(Arimo);
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this than by repeating this code over and over again? Can't I just have one base implementation of the code and list of values for the Typeface name, TextView name, and font name?

```
Typeface typefaceName = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttf");
TextView textViewName = (TextView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.resourceId);
textViewName.setTypeface(typefaceName);
```

**Update:** I suppose it's more efficient to set up a ListView:

```
    ListView fontsListView = (ListView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.MenuLayout);
    penis
    String[] fonts = new String[]{
            "Aclonica",
            "Amino-Regular"

    };
    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    planetList.addAll(Arrays.<String>asList(Arrays.toString(fonts)));
    for( int i = 0; i <= fonts.length - 1; i++) {
        planetList[i].setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fonts[i] + ".ttf"));
    }
```

Here is the XML:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="10dp"
android:typeface="sans"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
```

How do I iterate through the TextViews that are created so that I can programmatically set their Typefaces?

Comment: Why don't you use a adapter instead? The way you are managing TextViews is just like adapter managing items

Comment: @WUXudong I suppose I could but is there no way to do it without one? The TextViews are set in XML and all I want to do is change all the Typefaces.

Comment: If the only variable is typeface, I think you can put all your typeface name in a string-array? The AOSP Calendar uses it to store timezone info.

Comment: take a look at this one: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: @WUXudong I've updated my problem by changing it to a ListView. How do I set the Typefaces to the generated TextViews programatically?