# Setting multiple different Typefaces to the TextViews in a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-typeface

I have a ListView that displays a list of TextViews. I want each TextView to be displayed in their appropriate typeface. The names of the fonts which appear in the ListView as part of the fonts String[] array are spelled the same as when the Typeface is created.

```
    ListView fontsListView = (ListView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.MenuLayout);
    final String[] fonts = new String[] {
            "Aclonica",
            "Amino-Regular",
    };
    ArrayList<String> fontsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    fontsList.addAll( Arrays.asList(fonts) );
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fonts_simple_row, fontsList);
        final TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[0];
        for( int i = 0; i <= fonts.length - 1; i++) {
            textViewArray[i].setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fonts[i] + ".ttf"));
        }
    fontsListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

And the XML:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="10dp"
android:typeface="sans"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
```

Why can't I get each TextView in the ListView its proper Typface?

Comment: Create a custom Adapter by extending `ArrayAdapter ` class and set custom font inside `getView` method

Comment: The TextView array that you created is in no way linked or bound to your ListAdapter and in turn not connected to the ListView. You will need to make Custom Adapter class and set this custom adapter to your ListView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.fonts_simple_row,value) {
@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
     View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
     TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView); 
     textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/" + fonts[position] + ".ttf"));
     return view;
 }
 };

fontsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: This works really well actually. Does exactly what it's meant to. Just gotta make sure each font is spelled correctly or else nothing will work.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a custom array adapter and set font on get view method.

```
  public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
      private final Context context;
      private final String[] values;

      public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);

        textView.setText(values[position]);
        String s = values[position];
        if (s.equals("Arial")) {
            // set textView font to arial
        } else if (s.equals("Roboto")){
            // set textView font to roboto
        }

        return rowView;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Typeface only one time and use it. Avoid creating typeface in getview method.it will create every time you scroll if you are not maintaining reusability.

Use [ViewHolder](http://goo.gl/MASuHo) pattern for better performance in listview

Below i have try to given both things. I have given explanation in comment also. Please check it if it may help you.

```
public class AdapterFontViewHolder extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] values;
        Typeface typefaceArial, typefaceRoboto;
        private Typeface[] fonts;

        public AdapterFontViewHolder(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
            // Create Typeface only once and use it.. Path you can change as per your directory
            fonts = new Typeface[]{
                    Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Aclonica.ttf"),
                    Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Amino-Regular.ttf"),
            };
        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            TextView textView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder vHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                // Create Instnce of view if its null & store object in ViewHolder (a class)
                vHolder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
                vHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);

                //Set ViewHolder instance in convertview in a tag as a object
                convertView.setTag(vHolder);
            } else {
                // reuse as already converview is instansiated & it holds ViewHolder instance in tag
                vHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            vHolder.textView.setText(values[position]);

            //Here From Fonts array take Typeface
            vHolder.textView.setTypeface(fonts[position]);
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

**Set Adapter**

```
ListView fontsListView = (ListView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.MenuLayout);
        AdapterFontViewHolder listAdapter = new AdapterFontViewHolder(getActivity(), R.layout.fonts_simple_row, fontsList);
        fontsListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: How do I initiate this in my main activity? Like this ``ArrayList<String> fontsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        fontsList.addAll( Arrays.asList(fonts) );
        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new AdapterFontViewHolder(getActivity(), fonts);
        fontsListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);``