# Android ListView items disappear when scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview

I've loaded some pictures into a ListView using an adapter. When a user clicks on any row of the list I'm showing a checkmark at the end:

```
public class LazyImageLoadAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{

    private Activity activity;
    List<String> names,facebookbid;
    String sent;

    private  LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyImageLoadAdapter(Activity a, List<String> n,List<String> fid,String s) {
        activity = a;
        names=n;
        facebookbid=fid;
        sent=s;


        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.
                            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext(),"p");
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        if (getCount() != 0)
            return getCount();

        return 1;
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return facebookbid.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
    public  class ViewHolder{

        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
        public ImageView checkmark;
        public RelativeLayout friendsrow;


    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            convertView=null;


        final ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.planners_friends_listrow, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.planner_friend_name);
          (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.planner_friend_image);
            holder.checkmark=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkmark);
            holder.friendsrow=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.friendsrow);

           /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            convertView.setTag( holder );
        }
        else 
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();


        holder.text.setText(names.get(position));




        Typeface   face = Typeface.createFromAsset(convertView.getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/MAXWELL REGULAR.ttf");
        holder.text.setTypeface(face);

        ImageView image = holder.image;
      String link;


      if(sent.equals("planners"))
      {link=facebookbid.get(position);

      }
      else
      {
          link="https://graph.facebook.com/"+facebookbid.get(position)+"/picture?type=large";
      }


        //DisplayImage function from ImageLoader Class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(link, image);


        holder.friendsrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                boolean a=isNetworkConnected();
                if(a==true)
                {

                    if(sender.equals("settings"))
                    {

                    }
                    else if(sender.equals("savethedate"))
                    {



                        if(sid.contains(facebookbid.get(position)))
                        {
                            if(sid.contains("_"))
                            {
                                sid=sid.replace("_"+facebookbid.get(position), "");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sid=sid.replace(facebookbid.get(position), "");
                            }

                            nb_selections--;
                            selectedids.remove(selectedids.size()-1);
                            sidetitle.setText("Invite ("+String.valueOf(nb_selections)+") friends");
                            holder.checkmark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(sid.isEmpty())
                            {
                                sid=sid+facebookbid.get(position);  
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sid=sid+"_"+facebookbid.get(position);  
                            }

                            nb_selections++;
                            selectedids.add(facebookbid.get(position));
                            sidetitle.setText("Invite ("+String.valueOf(nb_selections)+") friends");
                            holder.checkmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String friendname=names.get(position);
                        String friendid=facebookbid.get(position);
                        String friendgender=gender.get(position);
                         Intent    resultIntent = new Intent(Friends.this,Newmarriage.class);
                         resultIntent.putExtra("facebookbid", friendid);
                         resultIntent.putExtra("name", friendname);
                         resultIntent.putExtra("gender", friendgender);

                    if(sender.equals("planner"))
                    {
                        resultIntent.putExtra("plannerid",friendid);
                         resultIntent.putExtra("imageurl","https://graph.facebook.com/"+friendid+"/picture?type=large");

                         setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                         finish();  
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        resultIntent.putExtra("plannerid","");
                        resultIntent.putExtra("imageurl","");
                     setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                     finish();  

                    }

                    }   
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                }


            }
        });



        /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row ***********/
     //   vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

The problem is: When the ListView is scrolled, the checkmark icon simply disappears. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks strange to me that you have all items rendered with same type of view and `getViewTypeCount()` method returning `getCount()`. I would expect `getViewTypeCount()` to return 1.

Comment: But getViewTypeCount() is returning 1 not getCount() !

Comment: As far as I can see from your code (condition `if (getCount() != 0)`) it returns 1 just in case you don't have elements in `facebookbid` list. Otherwise it returns `getCount()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code you set the Visibility of the checkmark when the user clicks on one of the items which then shows / hides the item. Now when the user scrolls the items are recycled and you dont have any code to check if the item has been checked or not.

So in short you need something that basically says

```
if (checked) {
  //set visibility of the checkmark to visible 
} else {
  //set visibility of the checkmark to gone 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

First you need to change `getView` method as don't reinitialize  `convertView` as `null` remove below line from `getView`

```
    public class LazyImageLoadAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

        private Activity activity;
        List<String> names, facebookbid;
        String sent;

        public ImageLoader imageLoader;
        private int size = 0;
        private HashMap<String, Boolean> mapClickStatus;

        public LazyImageLoadAdapter(Activity a, List<String> n, List<String> fid, String s) {
            activity = a;
            names = n;
            facebookbid = fid;
            sent = s;
            mapClickStatus = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();


            if (facebookbid != null)
                size = facebookbid.size();
// Give total size of the list item to getCount method
            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity, "p");
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        /*********
         * Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements
         *********/
        public class ViewHolder {

            public TextView text;
            public ImageView image;
            public ImageView checkmark;
            public RelativeLayout friendsrow;


        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // convertView=null;

            //It should not be null every time

            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {

                /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.planners_friends_listrow, parent, false);

                /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.planner_friend_name);
                (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.planner_friend_image);
                holder.checkmark = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkmark);
                holder.friendsrow = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friendsrow);

                /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


            holder.text.setText(names.get(position));


            Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(convertView.getContext().getAssets(),
                    "fonts/MAXWELL REGULAR.ttf");
            holder.text.setTypeface(face);

            ImageView image = holder.image;
            String link;


            if (sent.equals("planners")) {
                link = facebookbid.get(position);

            } else {
                link = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookbid.get(position) + "/picture?type=large";
            }


            //DisplayImage function from ImageLoader Class
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(link, image);

            // set the visibility of CheckMark ImageView based on the click status.
            if (mapClickStatus.get(facebookbid.get(position)))
                holder.checkmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                holder.checkmark.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            holder.friendsrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    boolean a = isNetworkConnected();
                    /// I dont know about the unique ID field in this so i took facebookbid.get(position) as a key
                    // To set click status of row item in hashmap.
                    mapClickStatus.put(facebookbid.get(position),
                            mapClickStatus.containsKey(facebookbid.get(position)) ? false : true);
                    if (a == true) {

                        if (sender.equals("settings")) {

                        } else if (sender.equals("savethedate")) {


                            if (sid.contains(facebookbid.get(position))) {
                                if (sid.contains("_")) {
                                    sid = sid.replace("_" + facebookbid.get(position), "");
                                } else {
                                    sid = sid.replace(facebookbid.get(position), "");
                                }

                                nb_selections--;
                                selectedids.remove(selectedids.size() - 1);
                                sidetitle.setText("Invite (" + String.valueOf(nb_selections) + ") friends");
                                // holder.checkmark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            } else {
                                if (sid.isEmpty()) {
                                    sid = sid + facebookbid.get(position);
                                } else {
                                    sid = sid + "_" + facebookbid.get(position);
                                }

                                nb_selections++;
                                selectedids.add(facebookbid.get(position));
                                sidetitle.setText("Invite (" + String.valueOf(nb_selections) + ") friends");
                                //  holder.checkmark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            // TO refresh view with updated checkmark status
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else {
                            String friendname = names.get(position);
                            String friendid = facebookbid.get(position);
                            String friendgender = gender.get(position);
                            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(Friends.this, Newmarriage.class);
                            resultIntent.putExtra("facebookbid", friendid);
                            resultIntent.putExtra("name", friendname);
                            resultIntent.putExtra("gender", friendgender);

                            if (sender.equals("planner")) {
                                resultIntent.putExtra("plannerid", friendid);
                                resultIntent.putExtra("imageurl", "https://graph.facebook.com/" + friendid + "/picture?type=large");

                                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                                finish();
                            } else {

                                resultIntent.putExtra("plannerid", "");
                                resultIntent.putExtra("imageurl", "");
                                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                                finish();

                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            });


            /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row ***********/
            //   vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```

**Suggestions**

- Inflate layout with parent attaching like below

.

```
convertView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.planners_friends_listrow, parent, false);
```

- Avoid mantaining status by using multiple collection(Arraylist or
  like that to display data) use Model Class or JSON or Arraylist of
  map etc.

Comment: The only difference now, is that instead of disappearing, they're repositionning

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34349311/1140237. You can refer this answer for base adapter related .. Explained in comment alsi

Comment: The link you gave me is about initializing the font once, this didn't help, In my code when clicking on the row the check mark icon appears/disappears, and when scrolling all the checkmarks are disappearing !

Comment: @MonzerYaghi answer updated with formatted code & comments also given